# How to create custom properties in user control?

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a user control with two fields:

```
public string OffText { set; get; }
public string OnText { set; get; }
```

After added this control in my form and fill `OffText` and `OnText` properties. In control's constructor i have:

```
    public FakeToggleSwitch()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (State)
        {
            CheckEdit.Text = OnText;
        }
        else
        {
            CheckEdit.Text = OffText;
        }
    }
```

And in debug mode i see that `OnText` and `OffText` are `null`. Whats can be wrong here? What have to i make with fields?

Comment: In WPF usercontrol you create [Dependency Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) not standard properties

Comment: Auto-properties have `default` value. And default for `reference` type is `null`. You can simply set their values in constructor (purpose of constructor is to construct object in default state).

Comment: i think you have to access the properties with usercontrol reference like below,Lets say your usercontrol on form has name "uc" then you have to use properties like this uc.OnText and uc.OffText

Comment: Sure i can set OnText and OffText values manualy, but it's not looks cool. Can someone give me example with `Dependency Property`. I have a problem with ` DependencyProperty.Register()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Those are not fields, but [auto-properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).

If you use auto-property and its default value should be different from `0` (value type) or `null` (reference type), then you can set it in the constructor

```
public string OffText { set; get; }
public string OnText { set; get; }

public Constructor()
{
    // init
    OffText = "...";
    OnText = "...";
}
```

Otherwise you may decide to use normal properties

```
private string _offText = "..."; // default value
public string OffText
{
    get { return _offText; }
    set { _offText = value; }
}
```

If you use `wpf`, then typically `UserControl` properties there have to be dependency properties (to support binding). Creating dependency property is easily done by using [code snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7d3wz0k(v=vs.90).aspx). Type

> propdp <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>

to get

```
public int MyProperty
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(int), typeof(ownerclass), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```